# Checkbox is not appearing checked after dynamically setting its value to true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a project in ASP.NET MVC. I have a page for displaying data where users can use checkboxes to mark different items and then makes changes to those items. On some pages, there are enough checkboxes that a "Select all Checkboxes" button is required. I typed up the code for in javascript and I cannot seem to get it to work no matter what I try. Here is my HTML:

I first loop through my viewmodel data and display a checkbox with an id of my Model's id for each checkbox.

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Data)
{ 
  <input name="selected" type="checkbox" id="@item.id" value="@item.id"/>
}
```

Each checkbox displayed on the page now has an ID of each database ID.

I then create this button

```
<a onclick="selectAll()" class="btn btn-primary">Select All</a>
```

That button corresponds to this javascript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                function selectAll()
                {
                    var stepIDs = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model.Data));


                    for(let i = 0; i  < stepIDs.length; i++)
                    {
                        var curr = stepIDs[i].id;                        
                        document.getElementById(curr).checked = true;            

                    }


                }
  </script>
```

I get the ID's again using the SerializeObject() command and then set each corresponding one to true (dependent upon how many are in the database).

On runtime, **the value of the checkbox successfully changes to true, but it does not display a tick in the checkbox**. I have also tried using Jquery to try and select it but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `id`s for this kind of functionality.

Instead, give the collection of controls you want to manipulate a `class` name.

Then, iterate over the elements with that `class` name and perform the actions required.

Here's an example:

```
One <input type="checkbox" id="chkOne" class="myChecks">
Two <input type="checkbox" id="chkTwo" class="myChecks">
Three <input type="checkbox" id="chkThree" class="myChecks">
<script>
    var chk = document.getElementsByClassName("myChecks");

    for(var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) {
        chk[i].checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Great idea to use the class.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
yourCheckBoxVariable.setAttribute("checked","checked");
```

or

```
yourCheckBoxVariable.click();
```

hopefully that helps. what you're doing is a bit out of the scope of my knowledge, but I have dealt with checkboxes not ticking before and both of those solutions above worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it did not work. Very frustrating as this was a good answer and I thought it would work!

Comment: Ugh that's annoying, I hope you figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var curr = stepIDs[i].id;
```

instead of

```
var curr = stepIDs[i];
```

inside the for-loop

Comment: Good answer but I actually have this in my code I just didn't correctly copy it over right. My fault, I edited the original post.